# Model.Result.getFormatted_address()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Hi this is my first question here, I'm working on a google nearby place app, I'm getting a crash every time I click on the marker place to get the details, and yes I have enabled billing in google developer API

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.androidnearbyplaces.Model.Result.getFormatted_address()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.androidnearbyplaces.ViewPlace$2.onResponse(ViewPlace.java:88)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is the ViewPlace.java:88

```
mService.getDetailPlace(getPlaceDetailUrl(Common.currentResult.getPlace_id())).enqueue(new Callback<PlaceDetail>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PlaceDetail> call, Response<PlaceDetail> response) {
                mPlace = response.body();
                place_address.setText(mPlace.getResult().getFormatted_address());
                place_name.setText(mPlace.getResult().getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PlaceDetail> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick explanation:

`mPlace.getResult()` is returning `null`. NullPointerException is being thrown because you cannot do `null.getFormattedAddress()`. You cannot call any method on `null` in Java.

Why does it return `null`? I cannot tell for sure without seeing more of the code.

Please read more about NullPointerException, maybe in [here](https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-null-pointer-exception/).